# Splitting sentences using nltk.sent_tokenize, it does not provide correct result

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to split some customers' comments to sentences using `nltk.sent_tokenize`. I already tried to solve some of the problems using the following code:

```
comment = comment.replace('?', '? ').replace('!', '! ').replace('..','.').replace('.', '. ')
```

But I do not know how to solve the following problems:

1. Customer used several `"."` after some sentences. For example:

   ```
   Think tool is a huge factor in this....i have only
   ```
2. Customer used several `"!"` after some sentences, such as `auditory subject everyday!!!!!`
3. some of them used combination of `"!"` and `"."` at the end of sentences.
4. Because I already used `replace('.', '. ')`, it also causes the following problem:

   Weight gain `(20lbs.)`, was split to `(20lbs.`  `)`

Any suggestion? I am using Python.

Comment: Completely free-form text is extremely problematic, so it is unlikely that a single static set of attempted fixes will work everywhere.  But the problems you describe could be fixed by reducing runs of repeated punctuation to a single instance, then add spaces after, then remove space before closing parenthesis.

Comment: @tripleee, thank you !. can you give a solution that I can reduce the number of repeated punctuations, such as "." or  "!".  ?

Comment: Easy enough with a regex.  `re.sub(r'([,.;:!?])\1+', r'\1', 'hello.....how are you????')`

Comment: @tripleee, would you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938210/regular-expression-to-replace-some-dots-with-commas-in-customers-comments

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Punkt Sentence Tokenizer. It is pre-trained to split sentences effectively and can easily be pickled into your code.

Comment: thanks ! I think for Punkt Sentence Tokenizer, I need both train set and test set. I have 220 customer comment for a product, do you suggest, I split the 220 comment to training and test set and then use it to split sentences ?

Comment: @Mary You could train the Punkt Sentence Tokenizer if you like but you could also pickle in a pre-trained version like so: `psenttokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')` . You could then just call the tokenize function on this psenttokenizer object passing the text as the parameter.